# HAML indentation error

Tags: haml

so I have the following HAML code

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse
            - if user_signed_in?
                %ul.nav.navbar-nav
                    %li
                        = link_to "All Journeys", journeys_path
                    %li
                        = link_to "New Journey", new_journey_path
                %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                    %li
                        = link_to "Edit User", edit_user_registration_path
                    %li
                        = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

I want to move the **link_to "All Journeys"** outside both of the if statement, right beneath **.navbar-collapse.collapse**. When I try to do so, it keeps on giving me **The line was indented 3 levels deeper than the previous line.** Error.

What am i suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have some unconventional (bad) indentation going on here.  Each line should be just one indentation below the previous line for proper nesting.  It's not clear what you want to pull out of the `if` statement, but this should at least get you a valid statement.  The first block with show if `user_signed_in?` returns true, the second block will show regardless.

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse
  - if user_signed_in?
    %ul.nav.navbar-nav
      %li
        = link_to "All Journeys", journeys_path
      %li
        = link_to "New Journey", new_journey_path
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
    %li
      = link_to "Edit User", edit_user_registration_path
    %li
      = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :metho
```